# Spring Cloud Dataflow Custom App stuck in Deploying state

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I created a custom Spring Cloud Stream Processor Application and deployed it as the processor step in a Source|Processor|Sink stream.  Everything seems to be working fine, but my custom app shows "deploying" in the dataflow UI. I'm deploying it as a SNAPSHOT from mavenLocal if that affects anything.  Am I missing something to let SCDF know the deployment was successful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual culprit, in this case, is the unavailability of Boot's actuator endpoints at runtime.

More specifically, it is likely due to Spring Boot's `/health` and `/info` endpoints not accessible by SCDF at runtime. In Spring Cloud Stream v2.0 and above, you'd have to explicitly add "actuator" and "web" dependencies to a Spring Cloud Stream application; they are optional from the framework perspective.

See more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-preface-actuator-web-dependencies).

With those dependencies packed in the classpath and upon the redeployment of the stream, you should be able to see the status as `Deployed`.

Comment: Thank you. Adding the Spring Web and Actuator dependencies to my custom processor's POM resolved the issue.