# Spring Cloud Data Flow stream deployment stuck in DEPLOYING status

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

`I have three spring cloud stream applications that are used to build data pipes.`

`Product Service: It creates product with name, price, etc...`
`Discount Service: It decides discount for given product.`
`Courier Service: It takes a product and dispatches the given product.`
`The applications are in the Github` [GITHub](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master)

`Software versions and applications are mentioned in README.md  in GITHub page`

[1. Zookeeper log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Zookeeper.log)

[2. Kafka Server log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Kafka_Server.log)

[3. Skipper Server log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Skipper_Server.log)

4. Dataflow server log

[5. Dataflow shell log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Dataflow_Shell.log)

[6. Product Service log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Product_Service.log)

[7. Discount Service log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Discount_Service.log)

[8. Courier Service log](https://github.com/radhakrishna67/spring-cloud-data-flow-example-master/blob/master/logs/Courier_Service.log)

`Stream Deployment Status`
[image]

`Apps runtime status`
[image]

I am running all the instances on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1686] local machine without any dockers.

`Stream is created and deployed. It is always in DEPLOYING status even after few hours as shown in the picture.

I am not very sure what is wrong with it. Could anyone help here?`

Comment: You may want to update the post with where and how you're running SCDF/Skipper. If it is Docker Compose or Minikube, it is likely that your environment doesn't have enough memory/cpu capacity to deploy all the apps. There are many posts on this subject as to how to troubleshoot this situation.

Comment: If it is not a resource constraint issue, you may want to check the logs of SCDF and Skipper. If the apps aren't deployed, there must be errors in the logs, which will indicate why they are failing.

Comment: @Sabby Anandan, I have updated the post with apps runtime status and logs. I could not find any interesting messages. I am running all the instances on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1686] local machine without any dockers.

Comment: @Radhakrishna, did you solve this problem? I also have the same issue.

Comment: @VSh, i have not yet looked into debugging of the issue. I will update the post, if i would find a solution for it.

Comment: @VSh, What version of the data flow did you use?

Comment: Thanks @Radhakrishna. I've just posted an answer with the solution that helped me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was to add [Actuator and Web Dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-preface-actuator-web-dependencies) to the project. For more details, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317616/7426774).